# Header file or library to share constants?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working with an LED library to make some [blinking lights](https://stwissel.github.io/presentations/fossasia2017/index.html#/). I found working with numeric Color values irritating, so I created my own list of gamma corrected Color name values (about 160 of them)

I'd like to share that and wonder what's the best format (in code). Should I have just a header file:

```
    #define COLOR_somename 42
    #define COLOR_anothername 223
```

Or would I rather define a class so one can access the values like this:

`ColorClass c = new ColorClass();
c.somecolor;`

What's best to be efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use C++11 you may use the scoped enum:

```
enum class Color {
    RED = 22,
    GREEN = 25
    // ...
};
```

Please take into account that scoped enums are not implicitly convertible to integer.

Another option is to use a regular enum:

```
enum Color {
    COLOR_RED = 22,
    COLOR_GREEN = 25
    // ...
};
```

Defines aren't good and in general I would avoid them as well as allocating a color object because it will cost you in a runtime.

Independently on what your choice it should be in a header file.

Comment: And then stuff the enum into a header file? I'm the total n00b in C (for Arduino)

Comment: @stwissel, yes, you should write it in header to be able to use it in separate cpp files.

Comment: Note that C++11 will require fairly recent versions of both the Arduino IDE as well as GCC.